# How to merge small files saved on hive by sparksql?

Tags: hive, apache-spark-sql

Like code below, insert a dataframe into a hive table. The output hdfs files of hive have too many small files. How to merge them when save on hive?
                               `myDf.write.format("orc").partitionBy("datestr").insertInto("myHiveTable")`

When there are 100 tasks, it will produce 100 small files.

Is using `coalesce` on dataframe a good idea? 
`myDf.coalesce(3).write.format("orc").partitionBy("datestr").insertInto("myHiveTable")`

Why hive configures as below do not work?
    
    `sqlContext.sql("set hive.merge.mapfiles=true")
    sqlContext.sql("set hive.merge.sparkfiles=false")
    sqlContext.sql("set hive.merge.smallfiles.avgsize=16000000")
    sqlContext.sql("set hive.merge.size.per.task=256000000")`

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: How big on average are the 100 small files that are being created?

Answer (score 0):

I encounterd this problem and find [issue-24940](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24940)

Use`/*+ COALESCE(numPartitions) */` or `/*+ REPARTITION(numPartitions) */` in spark sql query will control output file numbers.

In my parctice I recommend second parm for users, because it will generate a new stage to do this job, while first parm won't which may lead the job dead because of fewer tasks in the last stage.

Answer (score -1):

That's because **SparkSQL returns number of files which coresponds to the number of the spark partitions**. Even if dynamic partitioning config is on.

I faced the same problem. In my view, configurations mentioned above are only applicable to Hive on MapReduce engine: in my case, HiveQL commands work well (small files are being merged).

See [Hive architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOrJk.png) for more detail.